# query to retrieve workflow details from repository tables in informatica?

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-data-integration-hub

I need to get workflow details like wf name, objects used, run time and throughput from repository tables in informatica. can you help with the query?

Answer (score 2):

This will give you workflow run details -

```
select
SUBJECT_AREA folder_name,
WORKFLOW_NAME,
START_TIME,
END_TIME,
round((END_TIME-START_TIME) *24*60,2) time_taken_min, 
RUN_ERR_CODE,
RUN_ERR_MSG,,
RUN_STATUS_CODE
from 
REP_WFLOW_RUN
order by 2 ,3
```

You can not get through put for a workfolw. Its applicable for only for wprkflows. If you need session log, session details, pls query in `REP_SESS_LOG`.